# ASP.NET Textbox loses value after postback

Tags: vb.net, gridview, cookies, postback, shopping-cart

I'm writing a [shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WEjd.jpg) in ASP.NET and I want the users to fill in the count that they want in a textbox and place this count in a cookie so I can refill their count when they return to their shopping cart. I use an update button to update the cookie with the stored values, however when the page post back, it fills the textbox with the previous value. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
My Update button code:

```
If Request.Cookies("Aantal") Is Nothing Then
        Dim objCookieAantal As New HttpCookie("Aantal")

        For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
            objCookieAantal.Values.Add(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text, txtAantal.Text)

        Next

        objCookieAantal.Expires = Now.AddDays(30)

        Response.Cookies.Add(objCookieAantal)

        'fill
        If IsPostBack Then

            For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
                txtAantal.Text = objCookieAantal.Values.Item(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text)

            Next
        End If
    Else

        Dim objCookieAantal2 As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Aantal")

        For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
            objCookieAantal2.Values.Remove(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text)
            objCookieAantal2.Values.Add(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text, txtAantal.Text)

        Next

        Response.Cookies.Add(objCookieAantal2)

        'fill
        If IsPostBack Then

            For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
                txtAantal.Text = objCookieAantal2.Values.Item(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text)

            Next
        End If
    End If
```

My page load code to fill the gridview:

```
      If IsPostBack Then

            For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
                txtAantal.Text = objCookieAantal.Values.Item(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text)

            Next
        End If
```

Thanks in advance!
(I'm coding in VB.NET)

Comment: Upss I accidentally removed a comment :/

Answer (score 0):

You were right, I had to use the If not ispostback, now the only problem is that it doesn't fill the counts when I delete a product, my code for deleting:

```
 If (e.CommandName = "Verwijder") Then
        If dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim objCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Winkelmand")

            objCookie.Values.Remove(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text)

            Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie)

            dgvWinkelmand.Visible = False
            btnKassa.Visible = False
            imgShoppingCart.Visible = True
            lblLeeg.Visible = True


        Else

            lblLeeg.Visible = False
            imgShoppingCart.Visible = True
            'bepaal row index opgeslagen in CommandArgument eigenschap
            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
            Dim intTeVerwijderenItem As Integer

            ' bepaal rij dat button bevat van rows collectie
            Dim row As GridViewRow = dgvWinkelmand.Rows(index)

            'Verwijder item van cookie
            Dim objCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Winkelmand")

            intTeVerwijderenItem = Integer.Parse(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text)
            objCookie.Values.Remove(intTeVerwijderenItem.ToString)

            Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie)

            dgvWinkelmand.DataBind()

            'fill
            Dim objCookieAantal As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Aantal")
            If IsPostBack Then

                For x = 0 To dgvWinkelmand.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim txtAantal As TextBox = CType(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(3).FindControl("txtAantal"), TextBox)
                    txtAantal.Text = objCookieAantal.Values.Item(dgvWinkelmand.Rows(x).Cells(0).Text)

                Next
            End If
        End If

    End If
```